# Using Picasso to solve OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory, picasso

I have seen many answers on this issue which has not worked so far for me, the best option I got was using a Picasso to solve this, I have imported the .jar but am getting an error on the code I was told to use, I get an error on this(context) in the following line of code, say (context) cannot be resolved to a variable

```
Picasso.with(context).load(myBitmap).into(imageView);
```

This is the lines of code that generates the error, which I intend solving using Picasso

```
File imgFile = new File(data.get(position).get("path"));
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

This is my full code below

```
public class WidgetActivity extends Activity {
GridView grid;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 Bitmap rotateimage;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> maplist = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
LocalStorageHandler notedb;
ImageView iv_notes;
EditText content;
LinearLayout grid_layout;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
int n;
Intent i;
int s;
String[] tcolor;
public String path = "", name = "", color = "";

public void onCreate(Bundle os) {
super.onCreate(os);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

setContentView(R.layout.dialog_shownotes);
notedb = new LocalStorageHandler(WidgetActivity.this);

grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
iv_notes = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_note);
content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.content);
grid_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
i = getIntent();
n = i.getIntExtra("currentWidgetId", 1);
new getlist().execute();

 }

 class getlist extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> maplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 @Override
 public void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

 }

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
    ArrayList<String> filepaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor dbCursor = notedb.get();
    if (dbCursor.getCount() > 0) {

        int noOfScorer = 0;
        dbCursor.moveToFirst();
        while ((!dbCursor.isAfterLast())
                && noOfScorer < dbCursor.getCount()) {
            noOfScorer++;
            try {
            HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();

                filepaths.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/360notes/" + dbCursor.getString(2));
                filenames.add(dbCursor.getString(3));
                items.put("path",
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/360notes/" + dbCursor.getString(2));
                items.put("name", dbCursor.getString(3));
                items.put("time", dbCursor.getString(1));
                items.put("id", dbCursor.getString(0));
                items.put("color", dbCursor.getString(4));
                maplist.add(items);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dbCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    if (maplist.size() > 0) {
        grid.setAdapter(new GridViewImageAdapter(WidgetActivity.this,
                maplist));
    }

 }
}

public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
ArrayList<String> _filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {
    this._activity = activity;
    data = items;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(_activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.show_image, null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imgScreen);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    try {
        String[] tcolor = data.get(position).get("name").split(" / ");
        title.setText(tcolor[0].trim());
        title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(tcolor[1].trim()));

        if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("0")) {
            String text = title.getText().toString();
            SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
            span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, span.length(), 0);
            // title.setText(span);
        } else if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("3")) {
            // title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            String text = title.getText().toString();
            SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
            span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, span.length(), 0);
            // title.setText(span);

        } else if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("4")) {
            // title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);

            String text = title.getText().toString();
            SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
            span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, span.length(), 0);
            // title.setText(span);
        } else if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("1")) {
            // title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            String text = title.getText().toString();

            SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);

            span.removeSpan(text);
        } else if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("2")) {
            // title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
            String text = title.getText().toString();

            SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);

            span.removeSpan(text);
        } else {
            String text = title.getText().toString();

            SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);

            span.removeSpan(text);
        }

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    // TODO: handle exception
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    File imgFile = new File(data.get(position).get("path"));
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    /*if (myBitmap != null && !myBitmap.isRecycled()) {
        myBitmap.recycle();
        myBitmap = null;
    }*/
     //myBitmap.recycle();
     //myBitmap = null;
    Picasso.with(context).load(myBitmap).into(imageView);

    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            grid.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // grid_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            s = position;
            path = data.get(position).get("path");
            try {

                tcolor = data.get(position).get("name").split(" / ");
                name = tcolor[0].trim();
                color = tcolor[1].trim();

            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                name = "";
                color = "#000000";
            }
            appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                    .getInstance(WidgetActivity.this);
            UnreadWidgetProvider.updateWidget(WidgetActivity.this,
                    appWidgetManager, n, path,
                    data.get(position).get("name"), color, s);
            finish();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
  }
}

public void images(String path, String name, String color) {
 try {
    Bitmap bm;
    try {
        bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path);
        ExifInterface exifReader = new ExifInterface(path);
        int orientation = exifReader.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);

        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {

            matrix.postRotate(360);
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {

            // matrix.postRotate(90);
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {

            // matrix.postRotate(180);
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            // matrix.postRotate(270);
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
            // matrix.postRotate(90);
        } else {
        }
        rotateimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        iv_notes.setImageBitmap(rotateimage);
        content.setText(name);
        content.setFocusable(false);
        try {
            String[] tcolor = name.split(" / ");
            content.setText(tcolor[0].trim());
            content.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(tcolor[1].trim()));

            if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("0")) {
                String text = content.getText().toString();
                SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
                span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, span.length(), 0);
                // content.setText(span);
            } else if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("3")) {
                // content.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                String text = content.getText().toString();
                SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
                span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, span.length(), 0);
                // content.setText(span);

            } else if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("4")) {
                // content.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);

                String text = content.getText().toString();
                SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
                span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, span.length(), 0);
                // content.setText(span);
            } else if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("1")) {
                // content.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                String text = content.getText().toString();

                SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);

                span.removeSpan(text);
            } else if (tcolor[2].trim().equals("2")) {
                // content.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
                String text = content.getText().toString();

                SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);

                span.removeSpan(text);
            } else {
                String text = content.getText().toString();

                SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);

                span.removeSpan(text);
            }

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        grid_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = grid.getCount();
                Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(WidgetActivity.this,
                        WriteNotesActivity.class);
                intentAlarm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                intentAlarm.putExtra("max", s);
                startActivity(intentAlarm);
                finish();

            }
        });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    // finish();
  }
 }

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String resId) {
// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 400, 300);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resId, options);
 }

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;
if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
    // keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            || (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

 return inSampleSize;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help someone out there after several hours without an answer to this. I found a way of solving this without using Picasso in handling the outOfMemoryError. I added this line of code in my Manifest file.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

I added this to the entire application here as below:-

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

android:largeHeap is the instrument for increasing your allocated memory to app.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
well, you are using too much memory. remove those 3 lines of code :

```
File imgFile = new File(data.get(position).get("path"));
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

simply, you are assigning too much space to these instances and your phone runs out of memory. Just use my response and consider logging the file path so you can possibly use that without creating another file.

i think you used wrong implementation. Probably the context is not adressing correctly and therefore, i would personally use "this" instead. And for loading resources, their guide provides us with three implementations, see below:

pass drawable

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
```

pass uri

```
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
```

pass file

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

so therefore i would decode the image using this code:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(new File(data.get(position).get("path"))).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response, i implement this but am still getting a crash saying outOfMemoryError. is there something all still not doing right, using Picasso was the best approach, but i cant still get that to work for me. using this android:largeHeap="true" did. but am open to a better approach.thanks expecting your feedback

Comment: Post ur full code pls. Also are u testing on real device? the OOM error comes usually ehen u try to load huge bitmap

Comment: @ Traabefi i have made an edit on my post and pasted the full code. yea!!! you right am testing on a real device. exactly all you said is correct

Comment: You an answer to my prayers!!i cant say thank you enough @Traabefi Thank u! Thank u!! Thank u!!! Thank u!!!

Comment: even now the loading is much quicker and faster. thank you, you saved my alot of unnecessary stress. you just a blessing, thank you for sharing you knowledge. i wish i can accept the answer twice

Comment: I had this problem too, just remember to remove and set to null any kinds of bitmaps and files and such things, also input streams and everything that holds something big like bitmap or another file RIGHT after you use it. So you can avoid the problems. For bitmaps it's Bitmap.Recycle() anyways, glad to answer your question. :)